# Selenium WebDriver - getCssValue() method

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing a exercise to use cssGetValue method to retrieve the value from a particular web element's CSS property.

I have 2 questions:

1. why the cssGetValue method returned value 13px, which web element does the method actually referenced.
   1a. I want to get CSS property for section labeled as "By ID". how should I modify my code so I can get CSS property value for id="by-id" section?
2. I used driver.close() method, but it won't close the browser after the script finished. Please explain to me why driver.close() method didn't work in this case.

   Here is my code fragment:

   ```
   package wd_findElementBy;

   import java.util.List;

   import org.junit.Test;

   import org.junit.Before;

   import org.junit.After;


   import org.openqa.selenium.By;

   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


   public class SearchWebElements 
   {

   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   private String baseUrl= "http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example";

   @Test
   public void findElements(){
   driver.get(baseUrl);

   try{
       List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("by-id"));
       System.out.println("number of elements: " + elements.size());

       for(WebElement ele : elements){
           System.out.println(ele.getTagName());

           System.out.println("get the text for web element with id='by-id' ");
           System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
           System.out.println(ele.getText());
           System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
           System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("id"));
           System.out.println(ele.getCssValue("font-size"));

       }
   }

   finally{
       //driver.close();
       driver.quit();
   }


   }

   }
   ```

Comment: `getCssValue("font-size")` gives you 13px is correct. That's the font-size for `<div class="section" id="by-id">`. What do you expect? Ideally the ids are unique, you don't need `driver.findElements` and loop through.

Comment: @user1177636 Thanks for the reply. 1)I have trouble to find the CSS style associated with the `<div class="section" id="by-id">`. I used Chrome's inspect element tool (hop mouse over the By ID section), I could find the font-size property. 2) Could you show me the code to show the value for font-size without using findElement(By.id()) method? Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you are asking. You mentioned you got 13px by your code, which is correct, now you are saying `I have trouble to find the CSS style associated with the <div class="section" id="by-id">`. I told you no need to use `findElements`, now you are saying you don't want `findElement`? Look again carefully please.

Comment: @user1177636 Sorry for the confusion. I use web developer add-on for Firefox (verson 21.0). I am trying to find where or location on the style sheet shows the font-size value is 13px. 2) If not using `driver.findElements(By.id("by-id"));` and `ele.getCssValue("font-size")`, how would you identify font-size value associated with _<div class="section" id="by-id">_?

Comment: In HTML panel, there's a sidebar called `computed`, font-size is there. For the other issue, do you see difference between `findElements` and `findElement`?

Comment: @user1177636 using Firefox web developer tool, I was able to located the font-size property and its value. If I understood the difference between **findElements** and **findElement** is that findElements return a list of elements that matching the locate criteria, in my case it returned the first 'By Id' in an _un-ordered list_, so the corresponding CSS property for font-size is 13px. Please let me know if my understanding is correct or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, all correct.

Here's a screenshot of where to find `font-size` through Firebug.

[image]

Since the ids are supposed to be unique (at least for this page), you don't need `findElements` to find a list of elements with id `by-id` and loop through, instead, you use `findElement` to get the element directly.

```
try{
        WebElement byId = driver.findElement(By.id("by-id"));

        System.out.println(byId.getTagName());

        System.out.println("get the text for web element with id='by-id' ");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(byId.getText());
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(byId.getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println(byId.getCssValue("font-size"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For getting CSS value:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("by-id")).getCssValue("font-size");//similarly you can use other CSS property such as background-color, font-family etc.
```

For quit/close the browser after finishing the execution of script:

```
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

public class GetCssValues {

```
public WebDriver driver;
private By bySearchButton = By.name("btnK");

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}

@Test(priority=1)
public void getCssValue_ButtonColor()  {
    WebElement googleSearchBtn = driver.findElement(bySearchButton); 
    System.out.println("Color of a button before mouse hover: " + googleSearchBtn.getCssValue("color"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(googleSearchBtn).perform();
    System.out.println("Color of a button after mouse hover : " + googleSearchBtn.getCssValue("color"));
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void getCssValue_ButtonFontSize() {
    WebElement googleSearchBtn = driver.findElement(bySearchButton);
    System.out.println("Font Size of a button " + googleSearchBtn.getCssValue("font-size"));
}

@Test(priority=3)
public void getCssValue_ButtonFontWeight(){
    WebElement googleSearchBtn = driver.findElement(bySearchButton);
    System.out.println("Font Weight of a button "   +getFontWeight(googleSearchBtn) );
}

public String getFontWeight(WebElement element) {
    //Output will return as 400 for font-weight : normal, and 700 for font-weight : bold
    return element.getCssValue("font-weight");
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

output:

Color of a button before mouse hover: rgba(68, 68, 68, 1)
Color of a button after mouse hover : rgba(34, 34, 34, 1)
Font Size of a button 11px
Font Weight of a button 700

Answer (score 0):

The value is correct. You need access computed section in dev-tools

Add the property name in the `getCssValue` to get the info regarding same

Some Examples are :-

```
        System.out.println("font-size = "+ele.getCssValue("font-size"));
        System.out.println("background = "+ele.getCssValue("background"));
        System.out.println("line-height = "+ele.getCssValue("line-height"));
        System.out.println("color = "+ele.getCssValue("color"));
        System.out.println("font-family = "+ele.getCssValue("font-family"));
```

Refer:-

[image]