# How to access CSS properties of a node using firebug in java

Tags: css, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, firebug

I want to use firebug from within java code to access any properties (css, etc) for any of the nodes in web page. I donot want to use xPath to check for properties, instead I want all the available properties to be returned. Any suggestions to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, if I understand this correctly, I believe this question shows little minimal understanding of problem being solved.

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a Firefox plugin, which is a physical thing in your Firefox, not a library for Java. So you can't Firebug with your Selenium Java code programmatically. However, you can use keyboard shortcut to open up actual Firebug in your Selenium opened Firefox, but after that there's no way you can select a node and get CSS properties from Firebug window.

I don't understand what you mean by

```
 I donot want to use xPath to check for properties
```

If you want to check CSS properties using Selenium natively, you need find the element (by many means, XPath is just one of them). Then call `getCssValue()` to get specific one CSS property. There's no way you can have all properties returned at once using Selenium natively.

For example:

```
String bgColor = driver.findElement(By.id("myId")).getCssValue("background-color");
```

Here is a relevant question "[WebDriver - getCssValue method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17255611/1177636)" you might want to have a look

Comment: @funambulist: Looks like you have never accepted any answers before. Just so you know if this answer fixes your issue, please consider accepting it. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220697) Otherwise provide some feedback here.