# Java Program- Get the dynamic(Css/is) page Content

Tags: java, headless-browser

I can't able to get the dynamic webpage(Css/js) content Through Java. I ensured htmlunit, jaunt, webview and so on. Those Tools are Get the HTML(DOC) Only. ** MY question is Rendering Website Content With headless Browser in Java.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Webdriver. selenium webdriver has feature to capture inner css values

Comment: Thank @Sadik. Can you give Selenium webdriver sample program Url.

Comment: You can go through link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255611/selenium-webdriver-getcssvalue-method

Comment: Also can try with java script with webdriver more detail in link http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2013/09/road-to-verify-css-properties-values.html

Comment: I don't know.. that contain part of the program. can you show full program .@Sadik

Comment: Do you have any idea selenium webdriver ?

Comment: Thank @sadhik... its working fine.. http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-download-and-install-selenium.html.. but i have another doubt, how to get the Weppage content(not source code).

Comment: First you need to find out locator of page object element then use. driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getText() it will return text of those element.